# redirect page with parameter and parameter cantrain hide function of next page

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

i want to redirect my page to another page with hide function on next page. when i click on redirect link then page will be redirect as well as function of next page is also called.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#block_1').click(function () {
    window.location("index1.php");
});

});  
</script>
```

Mat be it is possible in J query

Answer (score 0):

redirect with `index1.php?hideIt=true`;

In `index1.php`

you can call the hide function like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(getParameterByName('hideIt') == true) {
    $('#someID').hide();
    //or use a function which will be called on page load
    hideSomething();
  }
});

function hideSomething() {
   //your hide function 
}

function getParameterByName(name) {
     name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
     var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
       results = regex.exec(location.search);
     return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Comment: dear. i wanna to redirect my page on another page with hide function . your code can hide div on same page

Comment: then add a get variable as param in redirect

Answer (score 0):

Try a url parameter as such.

```
window.location("index1.php?loadFunc=true");
```

The catch the URL parameter from the next page. use the following function to get URL parameters.

```
function getUrlParameter(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
       var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}
```

The on the load of the page,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(getUrlParameter('loadFunc') == 'true'){
         runHideFunc();
    }
})
```